# Description for Webservice parameters

Tags: c#, web-services

Is it possible to create a description for parameters used in an (asmx)-webservice?
I know I can set the description of the webmethod with the Description-property.
However is it also possible to add an attribute to the parameter to create description in the webservice for a given parameter

```
[WebMethod(Description = @"Get all approved friends <br /> 
    where rownum >= StartPage * count AND rownum < (StartPage+1) * count")]
public Friend[] GetFriendsPaged(int startPage, int count){...}
```

For instance in the example given above, I would like to add documentation that the StartPage is 0-based.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to do this, and no standard for what to do with the information even if you could add it. It's true that a WSDL may contain annotations for any element, but there's no standard about, for instance, placing those annotations into comments in the generated proxy class.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find any way of doing it. I guess you'd have to put the text into the Webmethod's description.

Answer (score 0):

So far, I have managed to put html tags in the desciption (like pointing to our wiki page)
like: 
`<a href=link>Service Wiki</a>`